# Understand Scala immutable Map behaviour

Tags: scala, immutability, autoboxing

I used a scala immutable map as per below.

val d = "4.55"

1. This is working fine.

   ```
   val  properties = Map("title"->"title" , "value" -> d )
   ```
2. Its convert from [String , AnyRef] to [String, Any]

   ```
   val  properties = Map("title"->"title" , "value" -> d.toDouble )
   ```
3. Cant convert from Double to Object , runtime error

   ```
   val  properties:Map[String,Object] = Map("title"->"title" , "value" -> d.toDouble )
   ```

   Why object cant accept the Double?
4. Working fine.

   ```
   val  properties:Map[String,Object] = Map("title"->"title" , "value" -> d.toDouble.asInstanceOf[Object] )
   ```

Cant understand the four scenario of Immutable Map behaviour.

Comment: I am a Java developer just passing by, but I have guess for You (since Scala run on JVM maybe it can help). In Java there type erasure for generics therefore the type information is present only at compile time. I don't think this is the whole picture but maybe it is related to this behaviour.

Comment: `val properties[String, Object] = ...` is not a valid Scala syntax

Comment: Yeah I have edited syntax , i forgot the colon

Comment: "Why object cant accept the java.lang.Double?" It can, but `toDouble` returns `Double` and not `java.lang.Double`.

Comment: @SagarVaghela with colon it is not valid either.

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov its valid like val  properties:Map[String,Object] =......

Answer (score 1):

**Most important of all**: Scala has no primitive types as Java do.

Scala's **Double** is a class, inherit from **AnyVal**, has it's own methods

But Java's Object is **the base class of all reference types**, aka...**Class**

So, what you did here is using Object as base class of Double.

In my opinion,
Scala's **AnyRef** is the corresponding type to Java's **Object**.
Scala's **AnyVal** is the corresponding type to Java's **Primitive Types**.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see froom the Scala class hierarchy...

[image: Scala class hierarchy]

... the Scala equivalent of `java.lang.Object` is `AnyRef`, and type `String` is part of that family, but a Scala `Double` falls under `AnyVal`. When the compiler has to reconcile those two types it will find type `Any`, which can't be promoted to type `AnyRef`/`Object` without coercion (i.e. a cast).

If you had `d.toSeq` instead of `d.toDouble` the compiler would have gone to `AnyRef`/`Object` straight away.